# The boundary must have no boundary...

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

It is more complicated than I thought. Let's make the hypothetical statement simpler.

> Suppose that an $n-1$ dimensional hypersurface is the boundary of a connected $\mathbb R^n$open set, then it must be a hypersurface without boundary.

Basically, I would like to know, "can a manifold with boundary in the plane be the topological boundary of a $R^2$ open set?"

Are there some simple proofs for this simple statement?

Old question:
The boundary of a "connected" $R^n$ open set must be a [$(n-1)$ dimensional hypersurface](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersurface.html) without boundary. This statement seems "intuitively correct" in my humble sense. Which theorem shall I cite?

Comment: Simple statement? I don't even know what a $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ surface is! What is it?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry is it the word "hypersurface" seem better?

Comment: Yes, that would be better.

Comment: If $\Delta$ is the closed unit disk of $\Bbb R^2$, then $\Delta\times\{0\}$ is the *topological* boundary of its own complement in $\Bbb R^3$. However, the boundary of $\Delta\times\{0\}$ *with respect to its natural* $2$-*manifold-with-boundary structure* is non-empty, and diffemorphic to $S^1$. Recall that the boundary of an open set of $\Bbb R^n$ *as a manifold with boundary* is always empty.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thanks for your comment. It is indeed helpful. Does your last sentence mean that "the boundary of an open set cannot be a manifold with boundary"? How to prove this/What is the reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit** to answer the question in its final form:

> Basically, I would like to know, "can a manifold with boundary in the
>   plane be the topological boundary of a $R^2$ open set?"

Yes. Consider the unit interval on the $x$-axis.

---

It's more complicated than that, whatever you mean by "hypersurface without boundary":

> A set is the boundary of some open set if and only if it is closed and
>   nowhere dense.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)

There are many such sets that are not hypersurfaces. Consider the boundary of the open set of all points in the plane both of whose coordinates are not integers. The boundary is the set of grid lines: points with at least one integer coordinate.

There are far more complex examples. The Mandelbrot set is closed, so its complement is open. The boundary of that open set is quite unlike any hypersurface ...

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I added the definition for hypersurface. So I think I first have to show that a closed nowhere dense set is a hypersurface?

Comment: @HighGPA See my edit.

Comment: You are definitely right! I did not ask the question in the right way. I guess if the open set is connected then the boundary must be a hypersurface? Do you think I should open a new question or just edit on this one?

Comment: I think you are trying to mix differential geometry with topology. The boundary of the open unit disk in the plane is the unit circle. Viewed topologically, that set is its own boundary. Viewed as a manifold, it is a manifold without a boundary. But even that distinction fails for you. The closed unit interval on the $x$-axis is a manifold with boundary in the plane. I don't think you are clear about the question you want to ask.

Comment: So my question is basically: "can a manifold with boundary in the plane be the topological boundary of a $R^2$ open set?"